# C# HttpListener - can't see the transport

Tags: c#, wireshark, httplistener

I am using HttpListener in my application. Both server and client are in my local machine. I am able to send requests from the client and send responses back from the server - all works OK.
The problem is that I am unable to view the http requests/responses using Wireshark. If the server and the client are on different machines then I am able to view those requests/responses. 
Does anyone know why it happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Wireshark itself as far as I can see.

This link explains it better: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback